# Не могу устранить ошибку в файле main.dart (Flutter)

Tags: windows, flutter

Помогите разобраться.
Создаю новый проект (или через строку или через vscode). В автоматически созданном файле main.dart находит ошибку.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',...
```

*build* подчеркнуто волнистой и ошибка следующая:
**Class 'MyApp' can't define method 'build' and have field 'StatelessWidget.build' with the same name.
Try converting the method to a getter, or renaming the method to a name that doesn't conflict.**

Удалял проект. Создавал заново. Не помогло.
Подумал, может где-то в файлах vscode что-то намудрил (хотя в них не влазил).
Переустановил и vscode.
Также удалил и папку **code** (backup сохранил) из **c:\Users\bla-bla-bla\AppData\Roaming**. Подумал, может там ошибка крылась.
Что сейчас имею? Абсолютно новая версия vscode. Удалены все настройки. Создан новый файл проекта. И все равно ошибка. Но самое непонятное то, что сегодня до этой ошибки я работал с проектами Flutter. Откуда она появилась, не могу понять.

Comment: Выполните `flutter doctor -v` и приложите отчет к ответу.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Сделал до вашего ответа (поэтому приложить актуальный отчет не получится).

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за помощь. Сделал до вашего ответа (поэтому приложить актуальный отчет не получится).
Тогда выдало "неизвестный статус лицензии". После  ввел команду flutter doctor --android-licenses. В ответ - не верная директория jdk. Я работаю в vscode. Плюнул на это. После этого создал снова новый проект. После нажатия кнопки отладки выскочило в нижнем правом углу, что что-то меняется (или добавляется или что-то другое. Не успел вычитать). В общем после этого все заработало как надо.